# Does the image of a linearly independent set remain linearly independent under canonical projection quotient map?

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space and $V_0$ be a *proper* subspace of $V$. Then we have the canonical projection map $\pi: V \to V/V_0$. Now consider a linearly independent set $S = \{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \} \subset V\setminus V_0 $.

**Question:** is the image of $S$ linearly independent in $V/V_0$ ? does this hold for infinite an infinite set $S = \{ v_1,v_2,\cdots \}$

**My Proof:**

Since the map $\pi$ is linear then for any linear combination of the images of $\{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \}$
$$
 \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \pi\left(v_j \right) =\pi\left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j \right) \overset{!}{=}0 \in V/V_0 \quad\implies \quad \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j \in V_0
$$
But the set $\{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \} \notin V_0$ is linearly independent, then it follows that
$$
 \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j  = 0
$$
and hence $a_j = 0$ for all $j \in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

I would like to know if there is a mistake in the proof, and whether it is true in general. Thanks in advance!

---

**Addition**

I realized when it was too late that I did not state the question as I had in mind. Instead of "$S = \{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \} \subset V\setminus V_0 $" I should have written "$\text{span} \{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \} \cap V_0 = \{0\}$ where $\{ v_1,\cdots,v_n \}$ is linearly independent".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, it’s incorrect.

Consider $V$ with basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ and $V_0$ spanned by $v_1+v_2$. All the hypotheses are satisfied, but no two-element set can be linearly independent in $V/V_0$, which has dimension $1$.

This can be extended to any space which has dimension greater than $2$, even infinite. Suppose $B$ is a basis of $V$, with $v_1,v_2\in B$ distinct (they exist by assumption). Then with $S=B$ and $V_0$ spanned by $v_1+v_2$, you have $\pi(v_1+v_2)\in V_0$, so the set $\pi(S)$ is not linearly independent.

---

#### Addition

The statement is true with an additional assumption, namely that
$$
\operatorname{span}\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}\cap V_0=\{0\}
$$
which is much stronger than $v_1,\dots,v_n\notin V_0$. When you have
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_iv_i\in V_0
$$
you can in fact conclude that the linear combination is zero and so, by linear independence, $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=0$.

Comment: @Physor I added the simple argument for the case you mentioned.

Comment: @Physor There's no point in adding a question for the infinite dimensional case. With the stronger assumption, the result is true also in that case.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I'll add the assumption to the question below without changing the previous content

Answer (score 2):

Consider the vectors $(1,1)$ and $(1,2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. The are linearly independent but they have the same projection onto $(1,0)$, which is $(1,0)$ and so their projection is not linearly independent.

Comment: I wanted to delete the question because it is not what I wanted to ask, is that possible without issues ?

Comment: @Physor yes, you can delete a question for any reason. You can delete your answers as well.

Comment: No I can't because there are answers on it, I'm sorry

Comment: @Physor well, even if it's not what you meant to ask if someone else has the same question they might find it here. There is no harm in mistakes of this nature.